# Android if same date out of two datetime ISO strings

Tags: java, android, datetime

We parse the following dateTime strings with a ISO format (in UTC):

```
private final SimpleDateFormat isoFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");
isoFormat.setTimeZone(getTimeZone("UTC"));

try {
    Date a = isoFormat.parse(a);
    Date b = isoFormat.parse(b);
} catch (ParseException e) {
}
```

Now that we have the `Date` objects (which is actually a datetime object) how can be the best way to compare if their dates are the same (ignoring the time aspect)?

Naive pseudocode:

```
if "08/01/2015" == "08/01/2015":
   print True
```

I don't mind use Calendar, but no Joda please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
    Calendar ca = Calendar.getInstance();
    ca.setTime(a);
    ca.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
    ca.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    ca.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    ca.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
    Calendar cb = Calendar.getInstance();
    cb.setTime(b);
    cb.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
    cb.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    cb.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    cb.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

    if (cb.compareTo(ca) ==0 ){
       print True
    }
```

Comment: No simpler way, huh? I was afraid so. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
if (a.equals(b)) {
  System.out.println("True");
}
```

Comment: You do not ignore the time part